# React native iap android build issue

Tags: react-native, in-app-purchase, react-native-iap

Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:lintVitalRelease'.

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
> Could not resolve project :react-native-iap.
> Required by:
> project :app
> > Cannot choose between the following variants of project :react-native-iap:
> - amazonDebugApiElements
> - playDebugApiElements
> All of them match the consumer attributes:
> - Variant 'amazonDebugApiElements' capability Testahel:react-native-iap:unspecified:
> - Unmatched attributes:
> - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.VariantAttr 'amazonDebug' but wasn't required.
> - Found store 'amazon' but wasn't required.
> - Compatible attributes:
> - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'debug' and found compatible value 'debug'.
> - Required org.gradle.usage 'java-api' and found compatible value 'java-api'.
> - Variant 'playDebugApiElements' capability Testahel:react-native-iap:unspecified:
> - Unmatched attributes:
> - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.VariantAttr 'playDebug' but wasn't required.
> - Found store 'play' but wasn't required.
> - Compatible attributes:
> - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'debug' and found compatible value 'debug'.
> - Required org.gradle.usage 'java-api' and found compatible value 'java-api'.

Answer (score 4):

****the solution was to add to /android/app/build.gradle inside the defaultConfig tag this line :** missingDimensionStrategy ('store', 'play')**

```
 defaultConfig {
        
        missingDimensionStrategy 'store', 'play'
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
```